# Typescript module declaration over multiple d.ts files

Tags: typescript

So if I have my main `.d.ts` definition:

`main.d.ts`:

```
declare module myMod {

}
```

And say I wanted to have my securty definitions in another file but under the same module. My thought:

`main.security.d.ts`:

```
declare module myMod {
    module security {

    }
}
```

How would you make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the answer.

Declare in the security `d.ts` the `module`.`name`. So in my case:

```
declare module myMod.security {

}
```

Comment: How would this work if your module name is a string? For example I'm declaring am module for a third party lib: `declare module 'ordercloud-javascript-sdk' {}`